# jwplayer full screen button

Tags: javascript, jquery, jwplayer

Is it possible to call the full screen function of jwplayer(flv player) through javascript or jquery? Like I want to create an External Full Screen Link not the usual fullscreen button that comes with the jwplayer?

Thanks!

Comment: Just so you know, just because your code runs on a ColdFusion server, doesn't mean that you need to tag your question as a ColdFusion question.  This should go under javascript, jquery, and jwplayer.  It doesn't really relate to flash, and really doesn't relate to ColdFusion.

Comment: @Dave thanks for letting me know. Isn't jwplayer flash base and should be tag with flash?

Comment: It is flash based, but the question has to do with the javascript events not the Flash source code.

Answer (score 5):

Due to Adobe security limitations `setFullscreen()` does not work in the Javascript API.

Comment: i read the documentation, but i'm guessing if there is no absolute way  to do that. even because on the progress bar the Fullscreen operation is allowed, so i would like to hope there's a way to do that even via script. it's not something so weird for video operations.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, check out `setFullscreen()` in the [JavaScript API](http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/jw-player-for-flash-v5/12540/javascript-api-reference).

Comment: It seems the setFulscreen() is not working. I tried in IE and FF. The other function of the Javascript API works like the resize but the setFullScreen doesn't work